# web2py, dictionaries, and html

Tags: python, html, dictionary, web2py

I've got this problem. I have a dictionary with keys and values and I want to do this:

```
Form_url : {u'b4eee942-0ee7-4413-aaab-9cfa9adda905': u'observaciones',
            u'79d352f8-d4d1-4d15-a1c8-f68dc1dcc75d': u'OPERADOR TRAINEE', 
            u'9bf43b36-64bf-456b-a382-b90493797196': u'Puesto al que postula',
            u'182af529-c01b-4345-a6b2-14811ff41269': u'ANUAL'} 

<table border="0">
{{for elem in form_url:}}
    <tr>
        {{if elem == '182af529-c01b-4345-a6b2-14811ff41269':}}
        <td>TIPO DE EXAMEN :</td>
        <td>{{=form_url['182af529-c01b-4345-a6b2-14811ff41269']}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {{elif elem == '9bf43b36-64bf-456b-a382-b90493797196':}}
        <td>PUESTO AL QUE POSTULA :</td>
        <td>{{=form_url['9bf43b36-64bf-456b-a382-b90493797196']}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {{elif elem == '79d352f8-d4d1-4d15-a1c8-f68dc1dcc75d':}}
        <td>OCUPACION ACTUAL :</td>
        <td>{{=form_url['79d352f8-d4d1-4d15-a1c8-f68dc1dcc75d']}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {{elif elem == 'b4eee942-0ee7-4413-aaab-9cfa9adda905':}}
        <td>OBSERVACIONES :</td>
        <td>{{=form_url['b4eee942-0ee7-4413-aaab-9cfa9adda905']}}</td>
        {{pass}}
    </tr>
    {{pass}}
</table>
```

I want my output to be in order with my html code

Like this:

```
TIPO DE EXAMEN: ANUAL
PUESTO AL QUE POSTULA: Puesto al que postula
OCUPACION ACTUAL: OPERADOR TRAINEE
OBSERVACIONES: observaciones
```

this is the exact format in which I want my output, but the real output is:

```
OBSERVACIONES: observaciones
OCUPACION ACTUAL: OPERADOR TRAINEE
PUESTO AL QUE POSTULA: Puesto al que postula
TIPO DE EXAMEN: ANUAL
```

which is the order of the dictionary, and not my html

How can I output according to my html and not according to the order in the dictionary?

Disctionaries are not in order so it gives me a random order for every dictionary I create.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a dictionary -- they aren't ordered:

```
Form_url = (
            (u'182af529-c01b-4345-a6b2-14811ff41269', u'ANUAL')
            (u'9bf43b36-64bf-456b-a382-b90493797196', u'Puesto al que postula'),
            (u'79d352f8-d4d1-4d15-a1c8-f68dc1dcc75d', u'OPERADOR TRAINEE'), 
            (u'b4eee942-0ee7-4413-aaab-9cfa9adda905', u'observaciones'),
) 

<table border="0">
{{for elem,value in form_url:}}
    <tr>
        {{if elem == '182af529-c01b-4345-a6b2-14811ff41269':}}
        <td>TIPO DE EXAMEN :</td>
        <td>{{=value}}</td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

Or, if you must use a dictionary, don't use a for loop, just emit the table rows in the right order.

```
# form_url as it is listed in your question.

<tr>
    {{if '182af529-c01b-4345-a6b2-14811ff41269' in form_url:}}
    <td>TIPO DE EXAMEN :</td>
    <td>{{=form_url['182af529-c01b-4345-a6b2-14811ff41269']}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    {{if '9bf43b36-64bf-456b-a382-b90493797196' in form_url:}}
    <td>PUESTO AL QUE POSTULA :</td>
    <td>{{=form_url['9bf43b36-64bf-456b-a382-b90493797196']}}</td>
</tr>
...
```

Comment: But what I introduce into the dictionary will not be ordered as well, so the first order still doesn't help me solve my problem

Comment: Thank you very much, I really apreciate the help.